# Python diff and get the new part

Tags: python, compare, diff

My question is pretty basic.

I need to diff to variables that are made by many lines and get only the new part of them. It is much simplier understand it in a example:

First variable:

> Hello
>
> my
>
> name
>
> is

Second variable:

> name
>
> is
>
> peter
>
> and
>
> I
>
> am
>
> blonde

I need to extract:

> peter
>
> and
>
> I
>
> am
>
> blonde

I need to do it in large files. How can I do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: split lines and do set difference

Comment: Yes, but if I do set(variable1)-set(variable2) I will get `Hello` and `my`. I just want to get the new one. Thanks anyway

Comment: Try set(variable2) - set(variable1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If repeats and order don't matter, this is very simple:

```
first = set(open('firstFile').readlines())
second = set(open('secondFile').readlines())

diff = second - first
```

If output order matters:

```
first = open('firstfile').readlines()
second = open('secondFile').readlines()

diff = [line for line in second if line not in first]
```

If input order matters, then the problem needs to be clarified.

If the files are large enough that loading them into memory is a bad idea, you might have to do something like this:

```
secondFile = open('secondFile')
diffFile = open('diffFile')

for secondLine in secondFile:
    match = False
    firstFile = open('firstFile')
    for firstLine in firstFile:
        if firstLine == secondLine:
            match = True
            break
    firstfile.close()
    if not match:
        print >>diffFile, secondLine

secondFile.close()
```

Comment: Jut an extra question. The first parameter is taken from a file but the second one is a variable in a buffer. For the second variable I am doing `second = data.split("\n")` but the diff result is not correct. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments on the question, one could do this:

```
first = set(x.strip() for x in open("tmp1.txt").readlines())
second = set(x.strip() for x in open("tmp2.txt").readlines())
print second - first
```

However, if we take "large" seriously, loading the whole files in before processing could use more memory than is available on the machine.  If the first file is small enough to fit into memory and the second isn't, you could do this:

```
first = set(x.strip() for x in open("tmp1.txt").readlines())
for line in open("tmp2.txt").xreadlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if line not in first:
        print line
```

If the first file is too large, I think you'd need to resort to a database.